# Setting pixels for larger icons in Android

Tags: android, icons, pixel

I have seperated the icons of my Android Application into two types, the **small** ones that include icons approximatelly from **28 x 28  dp** until **32 x 32 dp**, and the **large** ones, that are icons **60 dp x 60 dp**. I have to tell to my designer the number of pixels, the icons need to be done. So for the small icons I keep the standard guidelines for the different densities:

**xxhdpi: 144px xhdpi: 96px hdpi: 72px mdpi: 48px**

For the bigger ones my basic thought is, that they cover 4 times bigger surface, so the pixels must be 4 times larger to keep the same quality:

**xxhdpi: 576px xhdpi: 384px hdpi: 288px mdpi: 192px**

Should I keep those ones or should I go back to the standard guidelines conserning the bigger icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the icon set for an android application just needs the following resolutions:
xxhdpi: 144px xhdpi: 96px hdpi: 72px mdpi: 48px
There's no need to use big or small icons, since you can just define one set in the manifest.

if you want to adapt other images to different densities, just follow the above relationship:
4:2:1.5:1

Comment: Thanks I thought that I sould care about the size of the icons.

Comment: you just have to take into account the densities of the the screen, and place your icons into the res-xxhdpi folder, res-xhdpi, res-hdpi ... folders